# Using virtual or temporary geometry with PostGIS and pgRouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am attempting to find the shortest/fastest routes from GPS point to GPS point as described in this post: [Create closest point on multilinestring to use in shortest_path()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27452/create-closest-point-on-multilinestring-to-use-in-shortest-path)

I have seen many solutions like the ones presented to that question, where the answer is to create "virtual" points or to create points in a temp table, then run pgRouting against the original data and the virtual data.

How is this accomplished? I can't seem to find any examples of people using virtual points like they are pitched in the linked question's answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example of using temp tables to add points to a network here: https://github.com/alaw005/pgrouting_functions/blob/master/my_generate_network_with_additional_points.sql